# Changing navigation bar color to white, icons to dark, does not stick when hiding/showing app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make the bottom navigation bar white, with dark icons (Versus the default of black background with white buttons.

I am using this code in main.dart, where I us the SystemChrome method to set the background color and icon color. This looks great when I first open up the app.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ]);

    // this sets bottom bar to white
      var mySystemTheme= SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark);
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(mySystemTheme);
  
      
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => GBUserInfo(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'test',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          accentColor: Colors.yellow,
          accentColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
          buttonTheme: ButtonTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            buttonColor: Colors.blue,
            textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        home: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
              if (userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return SplashScreen();
              }
              if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
                return ZonesScreen();
              }
              return Login();
            }),
        routes: {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here it looks like I want when I open app.

[image]

But, if I minimize app, then click to bring to foreground again,
The buttons are gone, I'm assuming they defaulted back to white.

How do I set the navigation color/icon colors and have them stick with the app?

[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm experiencing the same issue @mike henessy

Comment: No, never found a good solution. The ones I had worked sometimes, but it seemed to randomly revert back to white text...so I ultimately just kept the black background.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a theme data of your desired choice and also make that theme permanent by passing that theme like `Themedata.dark() or ThemeData.light()`

```
 MaterialApp(
  themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
  home: CounterCoin(),
  theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
)
```

Like in the above example.

You can then change that theme using theme mode which has the following enums
ThemeMode.system ,  ThemeMode.dark , ThemeMode.light and use copy with to alter individual property u don't need system callbacks for changing theme this is a more easy and readable way .

Comment: adding ThemeMode and setting it to ThemeMode..light did not change the color of the system navigation bar. So, not sure how I can use what you've mentioned to change those colors?

Comment: You need to add two theme data with copy with and change themeMode using some statemanagement .